# Fix the "operating", "system" and "systems" tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

- [operating](/questions/tagged/operating) + [system](/questions/tagged/system) (i.e. [operating+system](/questions/tagged/operating%2bsystem)) should be retagged as [operating-system](/questions/tagged/operating-system)
- [operating](/questions/tagged/operating) + [systems](/questions/tagged/systems) (i.e. [operating+systems](/questions/tagged/operating%2bsystems)) should be retagged as [operating-system](/questions/tagged/operating-system)
- [operating](/questions/tagged/operating) by itself (i.e. [operating+-system+-systems](/questions/tagged/operating%2b-system%2b-systems)) then has little value; five of the six current ones should be untagged or retagged [operating-system](/questions/tagged/operating-system), the [remaining one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169697/what-are-your-required-software-development-operation-manuals) needs something doing with it.

Then also something needs to be done about [system](/questions/tagged/system) and [systems](/questions/tagged/systems). I'm not sure what's best with them. They're somewhat different, and yet they're likely to be confused by users.

Comment: I retagged the ones in case 2, and the `remaining one` in case three. There aren't hundreds of these, so manually retagging by small batches shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `[operating]` is now orphan. `[system]` and `[systems]` need a lot of work though, not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: Both should be burninated.

Comment: I don't think burnination is appropriate here.  In some cases, the tag is being used completely "correctly," like when talking about the `system()` built-in function/class in many languages.  Unfortunately the only way to correct the problem is going to be going through all 900+ [tag:system] questions one by one...

Comment: @Charles: I agree with you. And then, I just discovered the [os.system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os.system) tag...